# difference and relation between Facelet, Servlet, JSP, JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, facelets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)

I'm new to Java2E stuff. I'm seeing bunch of different terms like JavaServer Faces, JavaServer Pages, Facelet, Servlets, Beans and I'm a little bit confused. Can you give me a more clearer view of these terms? 
Thank you

Comment: Your question shows lack of effort searching on internet. If you have read the duplicate question info in the link, please update your question asking what exactly you need to receive a further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE is a whole bunch of stuff. There are many different implementations of it, and there are many technologies that can be used in the different implementations.

Link to reference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html

Quick overview:

Beans are objects that have getters and setters. They are used everywhere. There is a lot more to them than this, but until you understand what Java EE is, this will help get you through it.

Java Server Faces (JSF) is a technology that deals with the View of MVC (model-view-controller). JSP is as well. A facelet is a part of JSF.

A servlet is a class that processes HTTP requests and produces HTTP responses.

Servlets are a part of Java EE, but can be separate. To illustrate, a servlet can exist inside any servlet container. A Java EE application needs a Java EE container, which also has a servlet container, but provides much more. To understand the difference, compare Tomcat with Glassfish  or JBoss.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. But what do you mean by compare Tomcat with Glassfish? Are these terms related to the web server implementation too?